# What do I do when i need to add commits to the same release version after i tagged and pushed to pypi?

Tags: python, git, versioning, pypi

I'm using setuptools and setuptools_scm.

The version_scheme i use is release-branch-semver.

Let's say I create a branch release-0.1.0 and have 3 commits.

I'm done then I create a tag 0.1.0 from the head of release-0.1.0

I push both tag and branch to my github repository. Then I use twine to package the python library and upload to pypi as 0.1.0

Then i branch off from main to make a release-0.1.1 and do work on it.

After a few days later, I realized there was a serious bug on 0.1.0. So I checkout back to release-0.1.0 and added 1 more commit to the local branch.

So what do I do now?

I definitely don't want the faulty version 0.1.0 on pypi as it is. I'm already halfway doing 0.1.1. So creating a hotfix off main branch as 0.1.1 is also weird.

Can i replace the 0.1.0 in pypi? Should i delete the 0.1.0 tag on the github remote repo?

Comment: A tagged version with a release number must *never be changed*. Even if it's bad, leave it. The fact that it's bad means that you need to release a newer version, that's all. Make the fixed one be version 0.1.1; make any new version with a new *feature* version 0.2.x; the final number in this three-part system is precisely for these kinds of fixes.

Comment: If what you're doing so far (the not-hot-fix part) isn't *fixes* it should be 0.2.0, not 0.1.1. Minor revs indicate new stuff but compatible with old stuff; fix revs (the last digit) indicate fixes, and otherwise 100% compatible. In other words if I'm using version x.y.5 and I see there's an x.y.6 or x.y.7 that means there's a pure fix and I should take it right away, I don't even have to need any new feature. See https://semver.org/

Comment: Oh I see. Now i get the logic. What about calver? Given that major and minor are taken up for year and month what would be the equivalent of a feature number and fix number?

Comment: Oh nvm I realize I can follow Boltons and do a yy.minor.micro as stated here https://calver.org/#other-notable-projects. Thank you 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you released a version to PyPI that shouldn't be used by anyone, you can [yank](https://pypi.org/help/#yanked) the release. That means it won't be listed on the project page and it won't be considered by installers such as `pip` when searching for compatible versions (it's not deleted though and installation can be forced via `==`).

Working on `0.1.1` implies that this includes only fixes for `0.1.0`. So when you discover that serious bug, you can just include it in the `0.1.1` fix and release it. Then you can continue the remaining fixes on `0.1.2`.

Existing releases shouldn't be modified and hence, when you finish a release, there's no reason to retain the release branch. Typically you would tag a `x.y.z` release on the main branch and then build from there.